# Type Script - React Native: the correct way to pass parameters to the NavigationDialog function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, navigation

What is the correct way to pass the parameters to the `NavigationDialog` function so that it can be used wherever I want?

In my example I tried to pass the parameters but I think something is wrong with `isVisible` parameter.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Popup } from 'react-native-map-link';
import styles from './NavigationDialogStyle';

const NavigationDialog = ({ latitude: number, longitude: number, isVisible: boolean }) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const options = {
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    dialogTitle: 'open with',
    dialogMessage: 'what app to use ?',
    cancelText: 'close,
  };
  return (
      <Popup
        isVisible={isVisible}
        onCancelPressed={() => setIsVisible(false)}
        onAppPressed={() => setIsVisible(false)}
        onBackButtonPressed={() => setIsVisible(false)}
        modalProps={{
          animationIn: 'slideInUp',
        }}
        appsWhiteList={['waze', 'google-maps']}
        options={options}
        style={{ container: styles.popupStyle }}
      />      
  );
}
export default NavigationDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component should only have one argument, an object, often called props except if you use destructuring

```
const NavigationDialog = ({ latitude:number , longitude:number , isVisible:boolean }) {
    ...
}

// or
const NavigationDialog = (props) {
    // Here you can use props.latitude, props.longitude, etc..
    ...
}
```

Regarding `isVisible` you expect a props and a state to have the same name. You should chose between keeping the state if you want `NavigationDialog` to control its own visible state or if a parent does. Usually when dealing `Dialog` an event like a button click triggers a dialog which means the parent should own the visible state not `NavigationDialog`

EDIT: following comments

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [isvisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    return <NavigationDialog isVisible={isVisible} setIsVisible={setIsVisible} />
}
```

Comment: when i do as your first example its give an error: "Argument name clash"

Comment: can you write me your idea with my code ? i want see it coz as i did its an error

Comment: how you do my example with the props ?

Comment: I edited the answer to include what you're looking for. You have arguyment name clash because your state and the destructured prop have the same name

Comment: but how the function should be? can you show me ?

Comment: Which function? If you're talking about `NavigationDialog` and really want to have the `isVisible` state you'll have to make a choice and rename either the `isVisible` state or props